# C# - Accessing tree view control from another class

Tags: c#, class, treeview

I'm working on a Windows Forms application in C# with Visual Studio 2010.

- There is a form `mainForm`.
- `mainForm` contains a tree view control `xmlTreeView`.
- There is a self-written class `myClass.cs`.

Now, `myClass` needs to access the `xmlTreeView`. However I don't know a) how to access the form and b) which way would be best to do that.

I tried to implement an interface following [oleksii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733884/478406) but I don't get it. The main form of the application is defined like this:

```
public interface IMainForm {
  TreeView treeView { get; }
} 

public partial class mainForm : Form, IMainForm {

  public TreeView treeViewControl {
    get { return myTreeViewControl; }
  }

  // Some code here
  [...]

  RuleTree rt = new RuleTree(); //How do I call this with the IMainForm interface???
}
```

Another class `RuleTree` is defined like this:

```
class RuleTree {
  private readonly IMainForm mainForm;
  public RuleTree(IMainForm mainForm) {
    this.mainForm = mainForm;
  }
```

}

**How do I call the constructor of `RuleTree` with the IMainForm interface???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following.  Don't see it as code, it's just so that you can understand, you can modify it accordingly.

```
public class MyClass
{
     public void MyMethod(YourTreeViewControl treeview)
     {
          // Do what you need to do here
     }
}
```

Then in your forms code behind just instantiate MyClass and pass an instance of your treeview to it, something like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.MyMethod(tvYourTreeViewControl);
```

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, it makes sense as I had this in mind as well. I will give this a try and oleksii's answer. Will figure out which works better for my needs :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible approaches would be to use dependency injection here. `MyClass` would have a constructor that takes a `Form` parameter. Thus when you create `MyClass` it would have the form *injected*. For example:

```
Foo
{
    Foo(){}
}

Bar
{
    private Foo currentFoo;

    Bar(Foo foo) //dependency injection
    {
        currentFoo = foo;
    }

    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        //do something with currentFoo
    }
}
```

It will be better to use interfaces (or abstract classes), so instead of `Foo` you could inject `IFoo`, this largely decouples your classes, which is a good design decision.

Comment: I'd like to try this with implementing an interface but somehow I got stuck. That's wh I've chosen Brendan's answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

**I have commented my code please read comments, I can make solution available as well.**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        static class Program
        {


   /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        //Declare a static form that will accesible trhought the appication
        //create form called frmMain form or any other name
        //
        public static frmMain MainForm { get; private set; }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //comment out default application run
            //Application.Run(new MainForm());

            //create a new instance of your frmMain form
            //inside your main form add a tree view
            //Loacte this file "frmMain.Designer.cs"
            //Change treeView1 from private to public
            //  public System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeView1;
            MainForm = new frmMain();

            //before I show my form I'll change docking of my tree  view from myClass
            MyClass mine = new MyClass();  //done

            MainForm.ShowDialog();

        }


    }

    public class MyClass
    {        
        public MyClass()
        {
            Program.MainForm.treeView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible to access asp.net server side controls into other class other then their cs class e.g
`test.aspx` is a page
you can access test page controls only in `test.aspx.cs`
Other then this class this is not possible.

Comment: It's not an ASP application but WindowsForms.

Comment: This is not an ASP.NET question so your answer is not related.

Comment: @BrendanVogt are you ok? windows form is also an asp.net application. asp.net is just a technology nothing else.